# Animating the transition from Pressed to Normal button state

Tags: wpf, xaml, windows-phone-8

My `Pressed` state is lowering the opacity of the `Button` content.

I would like to animate the transition back from `Pressed` to `Normal`, so that it takes 3 seconds to happen. I tried defining a VisualTransition but it doesn't work. Pressing my button immediately goes back to Normal, I don't see the opacity gradually coming back from `0.5` to `1`.

```
<VisualStateGroup x:Name="CommonStates">
    <VisualStateGroup.Transitions>
        <VisualTransition From="Pressed"
                          To="Normal"
                          GeneratedDuration="0:0:3" />
    </VisualStateGroup.Transitions>
    <VisualState x:Name="Normal" />
    <VisualState x:Name="MouseOver" />
    <VisualState x:Name="Pressed">
        <Storyboard>
            <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetProperty="Opacity"
                                           Storyboard.TargetName="ContentContainer">
                <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0"
                                        Value="0.5" />
            </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
        </Storyboard>
    </VisualState>
</VisualStateGroup>
```

I would like to know what I'm doing wrong.

Comment: Do you use blend for create your animation? You can see your animation in real time. Really easy to create animation with blend.

Comment: I didn't use Blend. I just tried now, and it's not obvious to me how to use this tool in relation to my problem.

Comment: Create your storyboard (animation) with key. Create behavior => ControlStoryboardAction and link with your control. For exemple create an animation for a button with opacity from 0 to 1 in 1 seconde. Juste link to an other button et you will see the animation.

Answer (score 0):

Is it not working on phone or within dev environment using mouse?
If the latter, have you tried changing your VisualTransition to Pressed->MouseOver? With mouse it isn't possible to go from pressed->normal because mouse will still be the over.

Apart from that possibility, everything looks ok at first glance.

(A useful resource I've found is http://samples.msdn.microsoft.com/Silverlight/SampleBrowser/index.htm#/?sref=CustomTemplateSamples&id=4, which although for SilverLight should still be useful for WPF)

Comment: Not working on the phone (I can't try the emulator as my CPU isn't SLAT compatible).